# Работа с CFile::SaveFile

Tags: php, битрикс

Привет! Использую функцию `CFile::SaveFile`:

```
if ($_FILES['importfile']['type'] == 'application/vnd.ms-excel') { 
   $arr_file = Array( 
   "name" => $_FILES['importfile']['name'], 
   "size" => $_FILES['importfile']['size'], 
   "tmp_name" => $_FILES['importfile']['tmp_name'], 
   "type" => $_FILES['importfile']['type'], 
   "old_file" => "", 
   "del" => "Y", 
   "MODULE_ID" => ""); 
   $fid = CFile::SaveFile($arr_file, "/sms/"); 
   echo "file_id: " . CFile::GetPath($fid); 
}
```

Но каждый раз при сохранении она создает в папке `/upload/sms` новую папку и туда кладет файл. Как сделать так, чтобы он всегда ложился сюда: `/upload/sms` и при наличии там такого же файла перезаписывал бы его?

Comment: ну так вы же не передаете в old_file ID старого файла вот он и не перезаписывает. второй момет - в метод SaveFile насколько я помню передается путь относительно директории upload, так что вполне возможно что хватит просто "sms".

Comment: @НиколайСарры  а откуда я могу знать ID этого старого файла? Скрипт отработал, сохранил файл в ФС и все. ID я же нигде не храню.

Comment: ID у Вас в переменной `$fid` хотите чтобы старый файл перезаписывался сохраняйте его, а иначе как система поймет. Или используйте [метод `RewriteFile`](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/file/rewritefile.php) если хотите дописать информацию в существующий.

Comment: @НиколайСарры а куда можно сохранять `$fid`?

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет, то он хранится в БД в таблице куда пишутся данные. Хотите сохраняйте в сессию\куки\свой массив.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fid = CFile::SaveFile($arr_file, "/Директория в папке upload/", false, false, "Поддиректория")
```

В этом случае рандомные подпапки создаваться не будут

Answer (score 0):

в функции `CFile::SaveFile` есть незадокументированный параметр последний - имя подпапки, где будет лежать файл. Если параметр не задан, то создается новая рандомная папка.

Comment: Вопрос остается открытым. Зачем Битрикс генерит подпапку со случайным названием? И как это предотвратить?